# Local map of xwidget-webkit-mode?

Tags: web-browser, widget

In `xwidget-webkit-mode`, the command `M-x local-set-key RET S-<right> windmove-right RET` has no effect — the key continues to be bound to `xwidget-webkit-pass-command-event`.  Also, `M-x local-unset-key RET S-<right>` has no effect.

So, how do I modify the local map in xwidget-webkit-mode?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself: `xwidget-webkit-edit-mode-map` was active.  To bind Shift-Arrow keys to windmove, I did:

```
(mapcar
  (lambda (map)
    (define-key map (kbd "S-<right>") #'windmove-right)
    (define-key map (kbd "S-<left>") #'windmove-left))
  '(xwidget-webkit-mode-map xwidget-webkit-edit-mode-map))
```